# Networking-How to send data from a container to mosquitto container in the same network

Tags: docker, networking, mosquitto

I have a raspberry pi which is running a mosquitto docker container. This container contains file and all the configuration required to send data to IOT hub. I also have another container `data-container` which performs some set of steps and then it needs to send data to that IOT hub using mosquitto docker container. `data-container` has a python code which used paho-mqtt library to publish and subscribe to messages.

I have created my own network in docker `mynetwork` by using below command:

```
sudo docker network create mynetwork
```

This created the network `mynetwork`. I then started the mosquitto container by specifying the mynetwork:

```
sudo docker run -ti --net=mynetwork --restart=always -v /mosquitto/mqtt/config:/mqtt/config:ro -v /mosquitto/mqtt/log:/mqtt/log -v /mosquitto/mqtt/data/:/mqtt/data/ --name mqtt pascaldevink/rpi-mosquitto
```

I also started `data-container` using `--net=mynetwork`. So both the container are in the same network. Now inside the `data-container`, it collects few information and publish it using the below command:

```
publish.single("/machine/machine1/, "<data to send>", hostname=<hostname>)
```

I am confused as to what to use in `hostname` in publish.single. Should I mention the IP address of the mosquitto container in hostname.?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The container name is fine when they are deployed inside the same network. To be sure you can try to `exec` inside your container and try to `ping` the other container using the container name. This should work when they are inside the same docker network.

Comment: Okay so you mean to say I can simply use the container name in the hostname and it will work. I just tested this using the ip address & it seems to working fine. But using container name is the best option because ip address might change if the machine reboots.

Comment: @SAndrew Correct. Both will work, but indeed, if your container crashes and you have to recreate it, it will have the same hostname (and probably have some different IP). Also when you want to distribute your app for multiple users, when they deploy your setup they will all have the same containername but they will not have the same IP for every container. You don't want every user to change the publish.single step with its own container IP.